# Migrating to runtime permissions: How do you find all the current permission uses?

Tags: android, permissions, migration, android-6.0-marshmallow

Is there an easy way to identify all the API calls an Android app makes that need to be adapted to use runtime permissions in Android M (6, API 23)?

It appears that you just have to figure it out by testing, trial & error, or expert knowledge (eg: pouring over the API docs and your source code).  I expected that Google would release a migration tool, but I haven't seen any evidence of that.  *Not* doing so looks as though it will leave your apps vulnerable to runtime crashes if anyone disables access to a permission post-install, even if you aren't using the runtime permission tags in your manifest.

What are the best practices for migrating to runtime permissions?

Comment: "What are the best practices for migrating to runtime permissions?" -- tactically, stick to a `targetSdkVersion` of 22 or lower. Your app will behave as normal. If the user goes in and disables certain permissions, you should get back valid results from all affected API calls, just without much in the way of results (e.g., querying `ContactsContract` will behave as though the user has no contacts, which is a perfectly valid state regardless of runtime permissions).

Comment: If you remove all the permissions from your manifest, I think lint flags all the calls that need a permission...  ?

Comment: @krislarson I haven't been able to get that to work.  Could you confirm that the linter does that for you, or point us to an example? (No warnings are given for Camera.open(), for example, even with no permissions declared.)

Comment: Hi, did you find some way to find that uses? I am struggling with the same problem.

Comment: @kolczak I lead a team that built a deep static binary analysis for Android; we're re-purposing that tool to do this, since there doesn't seem to be a good solution yet.  It'll be free for limited use soon.

Comment: Sounds cool, keep me posted please

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't able to find any existing tools, so our team at Galois adapted a static analysis tool we created over the past ~4 years to identify permission-protected method calls in binary Android apps.

You can use it at:

- http://fuseanalyzer.com

There are more details here:

http://galois.com/blog/2015/10/fuse-analyzer-handling-runtime-permissions-android-6-0/